# making a dictionary that assigns letters to numbers then does math

Tags: python, dictionary, math

need a way to to take numbers from an input and assign the first number to the first character (and so on) in the input and then do math with it. For example, input: 1234 ab - cd output: -22
anyone got any ideas?

I know how to create a dictionary with assigning the correct variables to numbers and I have kinda figured out how to concatenate the letters so "ab" (from the example input) is 12 rather than 1*2. But now im stuck on how to make python recognize the math operator and do the math. Also I know abt eval but im not sure how to get it to work when i need to pull values from a dictionary first.

```
r = "1234 ab-cd"
    digits = [int(x) for x in r if x.isnumeric()]
    letters = [y for y in r if y.isalpha()]
    info = dict(zip(letters, digits))
    # up until now i have isolated the numbers and letters and created a dictionary linking them
    
    z = int(str(info["a"]) + str(info["b"]))
    n = int(str(info["c"]) + str(info["d"]))
    math = z - n

    
    print(digits, letters, info, math, z, n)
```

Comment: I suggest starting with `digits, expression = r.split()`. This works well if you can assume that the characters before the first space will always be digits. Then you will need to iterate over the characters in the `expression`, probably with some `if` statement to determine what to do with each character.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to parse the expression yourself the same way you are parsing the mapping (looking for math operators and figuring out the expression). Sympy might have some tools for that.

OR you are right that eval can also be used here, and that would be much simpler. If you can isolate the expression (for instance if you require that :space: there, then you can just split `r` and grab the second token) you can just run eval on that. Python stores the association of symbols to variables in a dictionary which can be accessed by calling `globals()`. Update that dictionary with your variables before calling eval.

You have another problem; the way you wrote your math is ambiguous unless you do some post processing. Python doesn't know that `ab` is `a` times `b`, it will interpret it as a variable named `ab`, you need `a*b` for this expression to evaluate.

```
>>> r = "1234 a*b-c*d"
>>> digits = [int(x) for x in r if x.isnumeric()]
>>> letters = [y for y in r if y.isalpha()]
>>> info = dict(zip(letters, digits))
>>> expression = r.split()[1]
>>> globals().update(info)
>>> result = eval(expression)
>>> print(result)
-10
```